# Python Selenium - How to extract element based on text inside span tag?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting some data from URLhttps://blinkit.com/prn/catch-cumin-seedsjeera-whole/prid/56692 with unstructured Product Details elements.

Using this code:

```
 product_details = wd.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductAttribute__ProductAttributesDescription-sc-dyoysr-2 lnLDYa']")
 info_shelf_life = product_details[0].text.strip()
 info_country_of_origin = product_details[1].text.strip()
```

As you can see the Product details elements are unstructured and this approach is not suitable when the Index gets changed from URL to URL

Hence tried this approach, which throws out a NoSuchWindowException  error.

```
info_shelf_life = wd.find_element(By.XPATH,value= "//div[[contains(@class, 'ProductAttribute__ProductAttributesDescription-sc-dyoysr-2 lnLDYa') and contains(., 'Shelf Life')]/..")
print(info_shelf_life.text.strip())
```

How can I extract text inside div based on text inside span tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is invalid. You can try

```
info_shelf_life = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[span="Shelf Life"]/following-sibling::div').text
info_country_of_origin = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[span="Country of Origin"]/following-sibling::div').text
```

to get required data

Comment: Could you explain "following-sibling::div" part please

Comment: @yashagarwal `p/following-sibling::div` selects `div` that located on the same *level* in DOM after `p`. You can chek [XPath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) for more details